# scope.$watch in angular directive does not work proprely

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular and Bootstrap.
I'm trying to replicate the functionality of ng-model for bootstrap checkbox. What i would like to accomplish is:

i would like that when i click on the checkbox (label really) the model change, and actually that works... but what does not work that when i try to watch the object for changes the behavior is weired, because i need two click insted of one for disable or enable the checkbox.
Moreover if inside the the label element that has as attribute cm-checkbox="model.prop" i put a {{model.anotherprop}} wont work (does not render anything).

From the documentation i understood that because i want the two-way data bind the scope must be defined as i did.

Thank you for your help!

I have the following HTML:

```
<label id="claim_free" class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" cm-checkbox="model.prop">
      <span class="icons"><span class="first-icon fui-checkbox-unchecked"></span><span class="second-icon fui-checkbox-checked"></span></span><input name="claim_free" type="checkbox" value="" data-toggle="checkbox">
      same lable text
</label>
```

And the following JS:

```
directive('cmCheckbox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {'cmCheckbox':'='},
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs) {
      scope.$watch('cmCheckbox', function() {
          console.log("first value for "+attrs.cmCheckbox+" is: "+scope.cmCheckbox);
          if (!scope.cmCheckbox) {
            console.log("checked");
            $(elm).removeClass("checked");
            $(elm).children("input").removeAttr("checked");
          } else { // false and undefined
            console.log("unchecked");
            $(elm).addClass("checked");
            $(elm).children("input").attr("checked","checked");
          }
      });
      $(elm).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentValue = elm.hasClass("checked") ? false : true;
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.cmCheckbox = currentValue;
        },true);
        scope.$parent.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
}).
```

Here is the jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/pmcalabrese/66pCA/2](http://jsfiddle.net/pmcalabrese/66pCA/2)

Comment: 1) don't see the reason to use watch here
2) could you please provide link to jsfiddle?

Comment: The reason to use watch is that if i change the model.prop from the controller i need to update the view as well. About the fiddle i was thinking about it, but will take some time to replicate what i'm experiencing since i also have bootstrap.

Comment: thank you for explanation, but I understand the global idea of using $scope.watch. But for your example it's not necessary. With jsfiddle it will be easier to show how to implement it

Comment: Not sure if it is the reason,but should'nt it be scope: {cmCheckbox:'='} instead of scope: {'cmCheckbox':'='}?

Comment: @user700284 does not change anything, you can use it both ways.

Comment: The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/pmcalabrese/66pCA/2/ "unfortunally" is working. i think the problem is that it conflicts with bootstrap in some how...